# iTunes File Sharing - Microsoft Office?

Tags: itunes, sharing, file, microsoft

Does Microsoft Office for iOS support iTunes' File Sharing feature?

Comment: What's your definition of Office for iOS? There are some apps that come to mind, but there's no guarantee any / all support that feature. Also, the apps don't even work without some sort of subscription. Which subscription type are you going to choose?

Comment: I am talking about Word, PowerPoint, and Excel for iOS. Those apps work without a subscription. When they were first released, they could only be read without a subscription, but that has since changed.

Comment: Thanks - I was glad to find the current versions don't need a log in to view files.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint v 1.13.1 on iOS 9.0 works with iTunes 12.3 to transfer files over USB to the app. You can view them in view only mode without needing an account or log in.

It's highly likely the rest of the apps work as well for iTunes to transfer files to and from the iOS to a computer.